# MSAL.NET+Xamarin.Forms: build error when adding the latest Microsoft.Identity.Client

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, msbuild, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to add MSAL.NET to an empty Xamarin.Forms project but I'm unable to compile it. After adding a reference to the Microsoft.Identity.Client nuget package  on the netstandard 2.0 project (Xamarin.Forms project), I'm unable to build the solution:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1962,2): error XA2002: Can not resolve reference: `Microsoft.Identity.Client`, referenced by `Grm.Assistencias`. 
Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Microsoft.Identity.Client`, or remove the reference to `Grm.Assistencias`.
```

Looking at the solution explorer, I see no reference warnings or errors.

here's the csproj file for the netstandard project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="4.9.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.0.0.497661" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And here's the Android csproj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{A7B816FB-9BBD-4CBD-B666-F45754F35326}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <TemplateGuid>{c9e5eea5-ca05-42a1-839b-61506e0a37df}</TemplateGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Grm.Assistencias.Droid</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Grm.Assistencias.Android</AssemblyName>
    <AndroidApplication>True</AndroidApplication>
    <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
    <AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>
    <AndroidManifest>Properties\AndroidManifest.xml</AndroidManifest>
    <MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>Resources</MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>
    <MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>Assets</MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>
    <AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>false</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v9.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>true</AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>
    <AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler</AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
    <AotAssemblies>false</AotAssemblies>
    <EnableLLVM>false</EnableLLVM>
    <BundleAssemblies>false</BundleAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>false</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Mono.Android" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client">
      <Version>4.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.0.0.497661" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs" Version="28.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="MainActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Resources\Resource.designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Resources\AboutResources.txt" />
    <None Include="Assets\AboutAssets.txt" />
    <None Include="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\Tabbar.axml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\Toolbar.axml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\styles.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\colors.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-anydpi-v26\icon.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-anydpi-v26\icon_round.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-hdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-hdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-mdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-mdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xhdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xhdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxhdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxhdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxxhdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxxhdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable-xxhdpi\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable-xxxhdpi\" />
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Grm.Assistencias\Grm.Assistencias.csproj">
      <Project>{039DA92D-24ED-44B5-8DCF-4BB2C6D935C7}</Project>
      <Name>Grm.Assistencias</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Any clues on what's going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your simple project? I added `Microsoft.Identity.Client` on my blank forms project but it runs fine on the Android simulator.

Comment: Hello. I've added an issue on github: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1233 (there's code and the output from the build). It seems to be related with VS 2017 to 2019 migration, though I still haven't formatted my machine...If there's any way to fix this without formatting the machine, please let me know...

Comment: It has been closed on github. I can't give you more suggestions as I can't reproduce this issue on my side. If you want to get more help try to open a support ticket here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6

Comment: well, there must have been something that went wrong on my machine... formatted it and it's working now...

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to follow your repro steps and I am unable to. It looks like the error is comming from Grm.Assistencias.csproj - is this referencing MSAL as well (directly or indirectly?).

If in the transitive closure of dependencies for Grm.Assistencias there is MSAL, you may want to take a direct dependency to MSAL.

Comment: Hello. Grm,Assistencias.csproj is the net standard project that holds the xaml pages used by Xamarin.Forms. And yes, I've added a reference to the Microsoft.Identity.Client nuget package on both projects (ie, I've added a reference to the msal.net nuget project to the net standard and android csproj files). Btw, I've tried following this sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2, but might have missed something...